# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable error when trying to click an element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to use Python Selenium to download an Excel file by clicking "Export to Excel" in this page:

https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI

In Chrome Inspect mode, I think the name of the element is "ete"

```
<div class="ete title_right" id="ete">Export to Excel</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI")

driver.find_element_by_id('ete').click()

html = driver.page_source
print(html)
driver.close()
```

However, element not interactable exception is returned when running my code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

[Updates]

I used Debanjan's method but TimeoutException is returned:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
#options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI')
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='textrow' and text()='FUTURES']//following::div[@class='ete title_right' and text()='Export to Excel']"))).click()

html = driver.page_source
print(html)
driver.close()
```

```
[root@mybox python-learning]# python3.6 web4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web4.py", line 16, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='textrow' and text()='FUTURES']//following::div[@class='ete title_right' and text()='Export to Excel']"))).click()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 0):

The page elements take some time to load on this page and the section you're trying to access appears to load last.  What you need to do is put in a wait until the element is visible before attempting to click it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ete")))
```

After this wait and the element is visible, you can click it.

Here is a site with good info on this:  http://allselenium.info/wait-for-elements-python-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Perfect except for the space at `By. CSS`

Comment: I've tried but TimeoutException is returned:

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

...implies that the desired element was not interactable when you tried to interact with it.

As you are trying to `click()` ideally you should induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementtobeclickable*. Moreover, there are two(2) elements with text as **Export to Excel** and I have considered the element which is at the top of the page beside the element with text as **FUTURES** and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='textrow' and text()='FUTURES']//following::div[@class='ete title_right' and text()='Export to Excel']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: download]

Comment: I've tried but TimeoutException is returned:

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: